# Recompiling a mod \ module in apache2

Tags: c, apache, compiler-errors, apache-modules

A bug was found in "mod_authn_core.c" which is an Apache module and a fix has been given to it,

it has been given in the simplest form of .c file (C code)

apparently i need to compile it and replace my existing module file and it should work

[Bug Report in Apache forums](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55622)

[Suggested (Working) patch to be replaced with (from the bug report)](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1554995)

it suppose to be very easy to do with the right knowledge and i think this question is generic and can help others most surely in compiling different mods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found out that apache2 has a built in compiler for mods called apxs2:

```
sudo apxs2 -c -i mod_authn_core.c

echo “LoadModule mod_authn_core /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_core.so” > /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_authn_core.load
```